# serializer for the nested Json in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following JSON. which I get from the api and i want to write a serializer for this JSON in Django, someone has any idea how to write it, I just wrote it down but it gives me "error invalid data or expected directory and got a list "etc. anyhelp will be highly appreciated

```json
        {
   "artikelNr1":133198,
   "artikelNr2":0,
   "sku":"133198.00",
   "statusCode":4,
   "statusText":"Manuell Bewirtschaftung",
   "saisonRetourenCode":0,
   "saisonRetourenText":"unbestimmt",
   "saisonCode":0,
   "saisonText":"SAISON",
   "geschlechtCode":1,
   "geschlechtText":"UNISEX",
   "rayonCode":0,
   "rayonText":"<RAYON>",
   "warenArtCode":6600,
   "warenArtText":"ACCESSOIRES/DIV.",
   "wuCode":66,
   "wuText":"ACCESSOIRES/DIV.",
   "waCode":6,
   "warenGruppe":"DESSOUS",
   "alterCode":20164,
   "farbe":"BLACK",
   "material":"PLASTIC",
   "bezeichnung":"'METRO BOUTIQUE GIFTCARD' CHF20",
   "pictureName":"art_133198_00.jpg",
   "picturePathLocal":"p:\\",
   "kollektion":"",
   "comCode":"METRO BOUTIQUE GESCHENKKARTE CHF 20",
   "lieferant":"...",
   "eKchf":0,
   "eti":20,
   "vp":20,
   "groessenCode":0,
   "groessen":[
      {
         "artikelNr1":133198,
         "artikelNr2":0,
         "artikelGr":1,
         "groessenText":"os",
         "sku":"133198.00.01",
         "istZl":463,
         "verkPeriode":-268
      }
   ],
   "zlQty":463,
   "productId":82482,
   "published":true,
   "categories":[
      {
         "categoryRoots":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Damen",
               "parentCategoryId":0
            },
            {
               "id":188,
               "name":"Geschenkkarten",
               "parentCategoryId":1
            }
         ],
         "id":188,
         "name":"Geschenkkarten",
         "parentCategoryId":1
      },
      {
         "categoryRoots":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Herren",
               "parentCategoryId":0
            },
            {
               "id":186,
               "name":"Geschenkkarten",
               "parentCategoryId":2
            }
         ],
         "id":186,
         "name":"Geschenkkarten",
         "parentCategoryId":2
      },
      {
         "categoryRoots":[
            {
               "id":3,
               "name":"Mädchen",
               "parentCategoryId":0
            },
            {
               "id":183,
               "name":"Geschenkkarten",
               "parentCategoryId":3
            }
         ],
         "id":183,
         "name":"Geschenkkarten",
         "parentCategoryId":3
      },
      {
         "categoryRoots":[
            {
               "id":4,
               "name":"Jungen",
               "parentCategoryId":0
            },
            {
               "id":180,
               "name":"Geschenkkarten",
               "parentCategoryId":4
            }
         ],
         "id":180,
         "name":"Geschenkkarten",
         "parentCategoryId":4
      },
      {
         "categoryRoots":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Damen",
               "parentCategoryId":0
            },
            {
               "id":376,
               "name":"Bekleidung",
               "parentCategoryId":1
            },
            {
               "id":21,
               "name":"Fanshop",
               "parentCategoryId":376
            }
         ],
         "id":21,
         "name":"Fanshop",
         "parentCategoryId":376
      },
      {
         "categoryRoots":[
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Herren",
               "parentCategoryId":0
            },
            {
               "id":411,
               "name":"Bekleidung",
               "parentCategoryId":2
            },
            {
               "id":32,
               "name":"Fanshop",
               "parentCategoryId":411
            }
         ],
         "id":32,
         "name":"Fanshop",
         "parentCategoryId":411
      }
   ],
   "productName":"Giftcard",
   "shortDescription":"Giftcard - Schwarz + Gelb",
   "fullDescription":"<p>Metro Geschenkkarte - die perfekte Geschenkidee für alle Gelegenheiten<br />Dient als komfortables Zahlungsmittel in sämtlichen Metro Boutique Filialen und in unserem Online-Shop<br />Die Geschenkkarte kann in jeder Filiale aufgeladen werden<br /><span style='color:red'><span style='color:red'>Nicht retournierbar!</span></span></p>",
   "flag":""
}
```

```
#---------- GrossenSerializer goes to the main object-------------#
class GrossenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    artikelNr1  = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelNr2  = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelGr   = serializers.IntegerField()
    groessenText = serializers.CharField()
    sku         = serializers.CharField()
    istZl       = serializers.IntegerField()
    verkPeriode = serializers.IntegerField()

#---------- rootsCategories goes to the Categries-------------#
class CategoriesRootsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id                  = serializers.IntegerField()
    name                = serializers.CharField()
    parentCategoryId    = serializers.IntegerField()


#---------- CategoriesSerializer goes to the main object-------------#

class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id                  = serializers.IntegerField()
    name                = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentCategoryId    = serializers.IntegerField()
    categoryRoots = CategoriesRootsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)


#---------- main json object-------------#
class RecommendationJsonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    sku = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    artikelNr1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelNr2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    StatusCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    statusText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    SaisonRetourenCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    saisonRetourenText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    saisonCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    saisonText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    geschlechtCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    geschlechtText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    RayonCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    rayonText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    warenArtCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    warenArtText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    wuCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    wuText = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    waCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    warenGruppe = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    alterCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    farbe = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    material = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    bezeichnung = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    pictureName = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    picturePathLocal = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    kollektion = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    comCode = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    lieferant = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    eKchf = serializers.FloatField()
    eti = serializers.FloatField()
    vp = serializers.FloatField()
    groessenCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    groessen = GrossenSerializer(many=True,  read_only=True)

    zlQty = serializers.IntegerField()
    productId = serializers.IntegerField()
    published = serializers.BooleanField()

    categories = CategoriesSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)

    productName = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    shortDescription = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    fullDescription = serializers.CharField()
    flag = serializers.CharField()
```

and my serlizer class is this one
when i try to run this code against is valid it fail and give me this errors

```
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list.', code='invalid')]}
{'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'}
```

Comment: can you please post the code along with stack trace for better understanding for you problem ?

Comment: @ Sukhpreet Singh you can look at the main code which i wrote it down. the errors i also mentioned ... may it help to find the issue clearly

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with your serializer,  you need to post the complete stack trace to identify the problem @zahid

Comment: False
{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list.', code='invalid')]}
{'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'} on terminal i am getting these two errors i do not know may be there is some other way to get a full detail of issue.. these two function give me these errors    print(serializer.errors)
   print(serializer.error_messages)

Comment: I have posted a modified your code for above json request. Please try it :
`ser=RecommendationJsonSerializer(data=data)`  and validate it with `ser.is_valid()` check for errors `ser.errors`

Answer (score 2):

Just build it up using [Serializer fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/). Something like this:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class CategoryRootSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    parentCategoryId = serializers.IntegerField()

class CategorySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    parentCategoryId = serializers.IntegerField()
    categoryRoots = CategoryRootSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

class GroessenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    artikelNr1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelNr2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelGr = serializers.IntegerField()
    groessenText = serializers.CharField()
    sku = serializers.CharField()
    istZl = serializers.IntegerField()
    verkPeriode = serializers.IntegerField()

class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    artikelNr1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    groessenCode = serializers.IntegerField()
    zlQty = serializers.IntegerField()
    productId = serializers.IntegerField()
    published = serializers.BooleanField()
    productName = serializers.CharField()
    grossen = GroessenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Comment: This would only help read the data and validate it. Create/update method still needs to be overridden to create/update the objects according to request, if saving the data to database is requirement.

Comment: @Toni Sredanović i am trying this serlizer but it is still give me a same error let me to share the whole code i guess it will be more easy to look the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly modified your serializer, you can try it with the posted json

```
class GrossenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    artikelNr1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelNr2 = serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelGr = serializers.IntegerField()
    groessenText = serializers.CharField()
    sku = serializers.CharField()
    istZl = serializers.IntegerField()
    verkPeriode = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        return super(GrossenSerializer, self).validate(attrs)


class CategoriesRootsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    name = serializers.CharField()
    parentCategoryId = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        return super(CategoriesRootsSerializer, self).validate(attrs)

class CategoriesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id=serializers.IntegerField()
    name=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    parentCategoryId=serializers.IntegerField()
    categoryRoots=serializers.ListField(
        child=CategoriesRootsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True))

    def validate(self, attrs):
        return super(CategoriesSerializer, self).validate(attrs)

class RecommendationJsonSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    sku=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    artikelNr1=serializers.IntegerField()
    artikelNr2=serializers.IntegerField()
    StatusCode=serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    statusText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    SaisonRetourenCode=serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    saisonRetourenText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    saisonCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    saisonText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    geschlechtCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    geschlechtText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    RayonCode=serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    rayonText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    warenArtCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    warenArtText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    wuCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    wuText=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    waCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    warenGruppe=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    alterCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    farbe=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    material=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    bezeichnung=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    pictureName=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    picturePathLocal=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    kollektion=serializers.CharField(max_length=50, allow_blank=True)
    comCode=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    lieferant=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    eKchf=serializers.FloatField()
    eti=serializers.FloatField()
    vp=serializers.FloatField()
    groessenCode=serializers.IntegerField()
    groessen=GrossenSerializer(many=True,  read_only=True)

    zlQty=serializers.IntegerField()
    productId=serializers.IntegerField()
    published=serializers.BooleanField()

    categories=CategoriesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    productName=serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    shortDescription=serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    fullDescription=serializers.CharField()
    flag=serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        return super(RecommendationJsonSerializer, self).validate(attrs)
```

Comment: same error i am getting ```{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list.', code='invalid')]}
{'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'}
 ```

Comment: Are you using the view your serializer  ?

Comment: yes i am using viewer infact in viewer i am fetching the data from the json through  ``` response = requests.get('http://localhost:8081/erp.json')
 data = response.json()    serializer = RecommendationJsonSerializer(data=data)
   #print(serializer.initial_data)
   data = {}
   print(serializer.is_valid())
   print(serializer.errors)
   print(serializer.error_messages)
   print("serializer.data")
   print(serializer.fields)
   break ```

Comment: can you please check if you are getting the exact json you have posted above in the request in your data variable. Otherwise fetch the proper key which contains your json data.

Comment: basically i put that json which i am giving to the project code. it is same

Comment: I think I found the bug, the problem was I gave the wrong data to the serializer. You were right that I basically looped through Json's list and instead cited individual items that I post here. I gave Json's list. that give me a mistake but you were right ...